# Creating short link through API and getting "API key not valid. Please pass a valid API key"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, firebase-authentication, firebase-dynamic-links

I want to create a short link through Firebase. I'm passing a valid API key that I used for notification. But I'm getting an error: API key is not valid

response is :

```
{
    "success": true,
    "message": "Link is genereated successfully",
    "data": {
        "error": {
            "code": 400,
            "message": "API key not valid. Please pass a valid API key.",
            "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT",
            "details": [
                {
                    "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.ErrorInfo",
                    "reason": "API_KEY_INVALID",
                    "domain": "googleapis.com",
                    "metadata": {
                        "service": "firebasedynamiclinks.googleapis.com"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

And my Controller is

```
class ShortLinkController < ApplicationController

    def create

        response = nil
        firebase_server_api_key = Rails.application.secrets.firebase_server_api_key
        response = HTTParty.post("https://firebasedynamiclinks.googleapis.com/v1/shortLinks?key=#{firebase_server_api_key}",
                  :body => JSON.generate(
                      {
                      
                    dynamicLinkInfo: {
                        domainUriPrefix: 'https://example.page.link',
                        link: 'https://example.page.link/?username=\(/user?.username)&user_id=\(/user?.id',

                        androidInfo: {
                        androidPackageName: 'com.abc.example'

                        },
                        iosInfo: {
                        iosBundleId: 'com.example.abc',
                        iosFallbackLink: 'https://apps.apple.com/in/app/example/id1528494636',
                        iosAppStoreId: '1528494636'
                        }
                        }

                      }


                  ),
                  :headers => { "Content-Type" => "application/json"}
                  )

        render_success message: "Link is generated successfully", data: response

    end

end
```

When creating the URL
Could you help me figure out what I'm missing/doing wrong

Comment: you have the reason stated in the error response - the API key is not valid. Do you actually send the correct API key? Is it the same as the one registered with Firebase?

Comment: I'm using the same API key that I used for notifications in Firebase

Comment: I would say the same, can you double check the API key is still valid? Maybe hitting another endpoint...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure which API key you used, but a Firebase configuration has many keys that are used in the client-side app. Those keys allow you to for example *consume* dynamic links, but they won't necessarily allow you to *create* a new dynamic link with them.

The correct place to find your key for the REST API is described in the Firebase documentation on [creating links with the REST API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/rest#before_you_begin) as:

> 1. Get your API key. You will need an API key to authenticate your requests to the API. To find your API key:
>
>    1. Open the Settings page of the Firebase console. If you are prompted to choose a project, select your Firebase project from the menu.
>    2. Take note of the value of the Web API Key field.